# Unable to convert a string from a list into a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a list of integers and floats of the numbers the person inputs. So if they input "1,2,3,4,5,6,7.2" the list_numbers would = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7.2]. For some reason when it gets to "7.2" it thinks "." is val (I added print(val) so you can see this in the output). Im new to python 3.6, I previously used 2.7 so excuse my ignorance

```
numbers=input("Enter 7 numbers separated by spaces: ")

print(numbers.split(","))

list_numbers=[]
for val in numbers:
    if val!=",":
        if '.' in val:
            print(val)
            list_numbers.append(float(val))
        else:
            list_numbers.append(int(val))



print(list_numbers)
```

Comment: Your for loop iterates character by character so of course at some point `val` becomes "."

Comment: for val in numbers.split(",")

Comment: @user189 I see, I thought just typing numbers.split(",") earlier would do that, but i probably would want to do numbers=numbers.split(","). Thanks though, it works!

Answer (score 2):

`.split` doesn't change your string as such, it returns a new list which you can then iterate over. You are however only printing the list result from `.split` and then iterating over the original input string character by character.

Assign the output of `.split` to a new variable and then iterate over that variable.

Hope this helps!